# $find returning null when retrieving telerik controls in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik

I am trying to write a javascript function to show and hide a telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel, but for some reason when I try to use the $find function it always comes back as null even after the controls are loaded.

I am new to asp.net development can someone tell me what is going wrong?

My telerik control .aspx code

```
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="ModalLoadingPanel" runat="server" Transparency="10" BackColor="#E0E0E0" Modal="true">
    <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 45px; margin-bottom: auto; width: 135px; height: 80px;"
        class="modalProgress">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
```

My javascript function that exists in a `<script>` tag

```
function showActivityIndicator() {
        var loadingPanel = $find("<%= ModalLoadingPanel.ClientID %>");
        loadingPanel.set_modal(true);
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("#<%= ModalLoadingPanel.ClientID %>").find();
```

$ is a function which takes a selector and if the selector is an ID it should be prepended with # sign.

Actually you don't even need find unless you need to do further filtration. So this will get you the tag:

```
$("#<%= ModalLoadingPanel.ClientID %>");
```